# Can "always @(posedge)" or "always @(negedge)" work on a register variable?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement some very simple logic to generate a pulse of a precise width. I am using an ICE40 FPGA dev board and IceStudio. I have a CLK signal with a period of ~83ns (12MHz), and I want to generate pulses with a period of ~1245ns, but different lengths (i.e. a high time of ~415ns and a low time of ~830ns, for example).

I figured that I could do so by making a rotating shift register 15 bits long and then toggle my output HIGH on the rising edge of the first bit, then toggle it LOW on the falling edge of the fifth bit. Here is the code I came up with:

```
reg [14:0] shifter;
reg OUT;

initial begin
    shifter <= 15'b01;
end

always @(posedge CLK) begin
    shifter    <= shifter << 1;
    shifter[0] <= shifter[14];
end

always @(posedge shifter[0]) begin
    OUT <= 1;
end

always @(negedge shifter[4]) begin
    OUT <= 0;
end
```

If I assign the individual bits of "shifter" to an output, I am able to verify on a scope that that shift register is working as expected; but despite this, the OUT remains LOW as if the "always" blocks were never triggering.

Every tutorial I found online that discusses the "always @(posedge)" or "always @(negedge)" blocks do it on some external signal like CLK or RESET. I am wondering I am committing some sort of rookie mistake by assuming it could also work on an internal register variable like "shifter".

Can anyone explain to me whether this is the case or not?

The following code does what I want, but I'm still curious why my original implementation doesn't work:

```
reg [14:0] shifter;
reg OUT;

initial begin
    shifter <= 15'b01;
end

always @(posedge CLK) begin
    shifter    <= shifter << 1;
    shifter[0] <= shifter[14];
    OUT <= shifter[0] | shifter[1] | shifter[2] | shifter[3] | shifter[4] | shifter[5];
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: the short answer to your question is 'yes'.

Comment: @mat: I provided some sample code. What else should I provide?

Comment: FYI, you can simplify `OUT <= shifter[0] | shifter[1] | shifter[2] | shifter[3] | shifter[4] | shifter[5];` to `OUT <= |shifter[5:0];`. Your original code failed because you were assigning `OUT` in two different always blocks which is not synthesizable.

Answer (score 0):

When making a register out of NAND gates, a rising edge triggered flip-flop takes less area, so that is what most people use.

Synthesis tools do not allow you to make assignments to the same variable from different (`always`) processes.

Comment: Okay, so this is a good rule of thumb: don't use the same output within multiple "always" blocks. It seems my synthesis tool is not flagging an error, but since this is an open-source tool, rather than commercial grade, this isn't surprising.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* to declare a sensitivity on the edge of a register signal, but this should be avoided in FPGA workflows. Most FPGAs use separate routing networks for clock signals and logic, so "bridging" a logic signal to a clock network is complex and will result in a suboptimal design with poor timing properties. In some cases, there may even be limits on the number of signals that can be bridged this way.

It is *generally not possible* to perform nonblocking assignments to a register from multiple separate edge-triggered `always` blocks. This implies a register with multiple clock inputs, which isn't a component which exists in most FPGAs or ASIC cell libraries.

Comment: It seems like my tools or my FPGA does not have the ability to bridge logic signals to the clock network, or the synthesis tools does not support it. Even when I try an alternative design that does not involve assignments from separate always blocks, I still am unable to drive the clock of one logic block with outputs of another.So I think my first newbie lesson is that what can be done trivially using 7400 logic does not necessary work as an FPGA design